# Where is get_header('shop') file in Woocommerce templates

Tags: templates, plugins, headers

I need to modify the **get_header('shop')** file in Woocommerce but don't know where it's located, if someone knows please help me out - thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`get_header( $name )` is a Wordpress function, that will try to load the file `header-{$name}.php` from your theme's root folder. If this file doesn't exist, Wordpress will load the default `header.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I'll try to upload my own version of header-shop.php and see if that solves it. Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: My problem is that on the regular pages of my theme, it displays an H1 header from the page title, but on the Product Pages it seems to be pulling from the same header.php and not header-shop.php (because that doesn't exist) but when I look in the header.php there is no reference to the single-product header tag that should logically make it act differently

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong file; I suspect that you should look into the single product template and not in any header template.

Comment: `if((is_tax() && taxonomy_exists('product_cat') && $current_tax == "product_cat") || is_singular('product')) {
   echo '';
  } elseif (((is_home()|| is_page() || is_single()) && intval(get_post_meta($post_id , 'title-show', true)) == 0) && !is_front_page()) { ?>
  <div id="page-header" class="container">
         <div class="page-header-content row-fluid">
             <div class="title span12">
           <?php 
      $title = get_post_meta($post_id, 'title-content', true);
      if($title == '') $title = '<h1>'.get_the_title($post_id).'</h1>';`

Comment: I think my problem is where it's the product taxonomy it show's echo '' but if it's my other pages I can manipulate it to be an H1.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, thanks for the patience, where would 'woocommerce_before_single_product' be located?

Comment: do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

Comment: If your problem is diferent to your original question you start another question because it is really difficult answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

[`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) is a WordPress function (not a WooCommerce specific one) and if passed a parameter should load a file named `header-<parameter>.php` from the theme root (or parent theme root). So there should be a file named `header-shop.php` in the same directory as `header.php` or `footer.php`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information - I've looked everywhere for that info in the theme files but it seems to be missing. If that file doesn't exist can I create it myself and will it pull from the one I create?

Comment: No I'm just using the standard 'Alterna' theme from Themeforest, no child theme of it

Comment: Ummm... you are concerned about "Woocommerce templates" and are using a theme from ThemeForest so... what is the connection?

Comment: Ohh...the theme I'm using has some modified woocommerce files that overrides the standard woocommerce files - does that make sense? I'm dealing with those custom woocommerce files from the theme

Comment: So your theme is a child?

Comment: Yes I suppose in that sense it is, sorry for the confusion :). How would I view the file that contains 'woocommerce_before_single_product' from `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );`?