# Fatal Error: get_header();

Tags: errors, headers

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

I can't get this working. I am using twentythirteen default theme shipped with wordpress. I have created a custom template called `table.php` and I also used `<?php template name ?>`. This custom template simply shows up all records in a database. Its working just fine but header and footer are missing and when I try to add header and footer of the current theme by adding `get_header` and `get_footer`, it throws a fatal error. Here is the code:

Just to mention, I used `index.php` that is inside twentythirteen folder, not from root folder where `wp-config` file or any other `index.php` for that matter.

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one of the
 * two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>



<DIV class="form">

        <form method = "post"  action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dbentry.php">
            First Name: <input type="text" name = "first">*<?php echo $first_error;?><br>

            Last Name: <input type="text" name = "last">*<?php echo $last_error; ?><br>

            Email: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp    <input type="text" name = "email"><br>
            Telephone: <input type="number" name = "telephone">*<?php echo $tele_error; ?><br>

            Gender:&nbsp &nbsp 
            <input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "female">Female
            <input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "male">Male
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value ="submit" name="submit"><br>


        </form>
 </DIV>    

        <form action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/tab.php"     method="post">
            <input type="submit" name = 'submit2' value = 'http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=11'>
        </form>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Here is the code where the call will go after pressing the "Show all records" button.**

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying all pages
     *
     * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
     * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that other
     * 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
     * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
     */

     /* 
     Template name: tab
     */

    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="table">
        <table class = "border">
            <?php

               require "db.php";

               if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM person";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    $row = '';
                    $id = "";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th><b>ID</b></th>";
                    echo "<th><b>FIRST</b></th>";
                    echo "<th><b>LAST</b></th>";
                    echo "<th><b>EMAIL</b></th>";
                    echo "<th><b>TELEPHONE</b></th>";
                    echo "<th><b>GENDER</b></th>";
                    echo "<th  scope='row'>EDIT</th>";
                    echo "<th>DELETE</th>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>this is working just fine</tr>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        $id = $row['ID'];
            echo $id ;

                        echo "<tr><td>".$row['ID']."</td><td>".$row['First']."</td><td>".$row['Last']."</td><td>".$row['Email']."</td><td>".$row['Telephone'].
                        "</td><td>".$row['Gender']."</td><td>"."<a href='edit.php?ID=$id'><input type='button' class = 'edit' value = 'Edit'></a>"."</td><td>"."<a href='delete.php?ID=$id'><input type='button' class = 'del' value='Delete'></a>"."</td></tr>";

                    }

                    mysqli_close($connection);

               } 
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>jsdnsdjnsjd</tr>
    </table>



        <form action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="new" value="New Entry" class = "new">
        </form>




    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load template files directly. WordPress is not loaded in that context, so you have no access to its functions. Create a page in WordPress admin, and assign your template to that page, then point your link to that page rather than directly to the template file.

Comment: I did that but if i simply attach a permalink to a button of that page the page title still shows up in top menu and also after assigning permalink to a button table.php does't show any database records but without page it works just fine but no header and footer of the theme.

Comment: If you want to exclude a page from a menu, that's a separate issue. For querying the database, you should be using the [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Maybe:[Where is get_header('shop') file in Woocommerce templates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113123/where-is-get-headershop-file-in-woocommerce-templates)

I hope I could help.